# LDAP server is not running

Tags: ldap

I'm using Directory studio with open JDK 21.
I have created a new server when i try to run it, it is immediately stopped.
I'm using default configuration for the LDAP server did not change anything according to this page
[text](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/odm/8.9.2?topic=registries-task-preparing-ldap-environment)
I searche in stackoverflow forum and they says that it is compatible with JDK11 but not all version.

[Image from Apache Directory Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8IIc.jpg)

I have tried to edit ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini as following but did not work:

```
 -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.0.v20200915-1508.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.0.v20200915-1442
/studio-rcp/resources/icons/linux/studio.xpm
###
#Uncomment_to_configure_the_language
#https://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#how-to-set-the-language-of-studio
#-nl
#en
###
#Uncomment_to_configure_Java_version_to_use
#https://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#how-to-set-the-java-vm-to-use
#-vm
#/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin/java
-vm

C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-21.0.1\bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=21
###
#Uncomment_to_configure_heap_memory
#https://directory.apache.org/studio/faqs.html#how-to-increase-the-heap-memory
#-Xms1g
#-Xmx2g
```

Can anyone help on this topic?